# StopPropagation() with SVG element and G

Tags: d3.js, svg, dom-events, stoppropagation

I created an SVG element with an `.on("click")` behavior and appended g elements with `.on("click")` and thought that I could use `d3.event.stopPropagation()` to keep the SVG click event from firing with the g click event. Instead, both events continue to fire. So I must be placing `stopPropagatio`n in the wrong place.

```
svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 800)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

sites = svg.selectAll("g.sites")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .on("click", siteClick)
    ;

sites.append("svg:circle")                
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr("class", "sites")
    ;

function mousedown() {
    console.log("mouseDown");
}

function siteClick(d, i) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("siteClick");
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the `click` and `mousedown` events. Calling `stopPropagation` will only prevent propagation of a single event at a time, and these are separate events.

Typically, a click gesture will cause `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click` events, in that order.

You can keep the `click` event handler on the child elements and add a `mousedown` event handler with a `stopPropagation` call, and that should achieve what you're after.

Here is [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/3186840) demonstrating its use in a similar situation to yours.

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm still not clear on how the code would look. I need the event on the <svg> to be a mousedown event and I need the event on the <g> to be a click event. I updated sites to include the following but with no change:        .on('mousedown', function(){
       d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      })

Comment: You need to use `d3.event.stopPropagation()`. Your code will not work, since `d3.event.sourceEvent` is undefined. I've added an example for you now, too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried event, event.source and event.target with no effect. I was just copypasting various stopPropagation() terminology used in other D3 demos. But your demo is great, and exactly what I need to understand it.

Comment: Great link, explains it perfectly